# Как обратиться к объекту из связанной бд в html файле

Tags: python, django

Пытаюсь понять, какой нужен синтаксис, чтобы обратиться к одному объекту из связанной "бд" не через терминал, а запросив в "html" файл через контекст.

Например в цикле `for`:

```
<ul>
{% for parItem in blog_ident.myblogparagraph_set.all %}  
<li>{{ parItem.paragraph }}</li>  
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

- `blog_ident` - переданный через контекст элемент основной "бд" с определённым `primary key`.
- myblogparagraph_set - это queryset из всех элементов связанной "бд" `myBlogParagraph`.

Цикл `for` сам обращается к каждому и выводит параметр `paragraph` каждого по порядку, но мне, предположим, нужен объект из связанной "бд" с `pk=1`.

Через терминал это бы выглядело как:

`blog_ident.myblogparagraph_set.get(pk=1).paragraph`

Как должен выглядеть запрос в "html" файле?

Comment: Этого не должно быть в шаблоне (который вы почему-то называете html-файлом), это должно быть в представлении (views.py)

Comment: да, спасибо, именно шаблон я и имел ввиду.

Comment: прошу прощения, я совсем новичок в джанго  мне показалось, что переданный через context во views "родительский" объект сам по себе передаст связанный с ним массив объектов.  ответ на мой вопрос был на поверхности: all_blogPar.1.paragraph, где all_blogPar - переданный через контекст массив связанных объектов.